# AWK for saving read patterns in different fields

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep

I use `grep` with different regular expressions to get what i want from a long string. I `grep` each pattern and store the result in a variable, later I `paste` the lists from different variables to make my table.

Like this:

```
FIELD_A=$(grep -o 'pattern1' Longstringfile)
FIELD_B=$(grep -o 'pattern2' Longstringfile)
FIELD_C=$(grep -o 'pattern3' Longstringfile)
FIELD_D=$(grep -o 'pattern4' Longstringfile)
paste <(echo $FIELD_A |tr ' ' '\n') <(echo $FIELD_b |tr ' ' '\n') <(echo $FIELD_c |tr ' '    '\n') <(echo $FIELD_d |tr ' ' '\n') > Resultfile
```

Can I do this simpler by using AWK?

When I accomplished the task with this thing I thought: It looks like going all around the town to finally get to the house of my neighbor. Later I was getting into AWK and I found out that it is a great thing to use with this kind of things, the problem is that I don't know much about it, I'm learning but sometimes tutorials goes in a different direction.

Comment: In principle the `grep -o` can match the given pattern many times on a single line. Is this needed for your particular case?

Comment: Yes it gives me a bunch of things(a list) matching the pattern. It's important to say that the number of elements that I got as an output from the greps is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
awk -f e.awk Longstringfile > Resultfile
```

where `e.awk` is:

```
BEGIN {
    w[1]="pattern1"
    w[2]="pattern2"
    w[3]="pattern3"
    w[4]="pattern4"
}
{
    nmax=0
    for (i=1; i<=4; i++) {
        line=$0
        k=0
        while (match(line,w[i],r)) {
            line=substr(line,RSTART+RLENGTH)
            n=split(r[0],q)
            for (j=1; j<=n; j++)
                a[i,j+k+N]=q[j]
            k=k+n
        }
        if (k>nmax) nmax=k
    }
    N=N+nmax
}

END {
    for (j=1; j<=N; j++)
        print a[1,j] "\t" a[2,j] "\t" a[3,j] "\t" a[4,j]
}
```